# Regex string pattern for filename

Tags: javascript, regex

I am uploading a file and I need to check whether the filename belongs to a particular pattern or not.

**Example: AL-13-Annual DSH Audit.pdf**

The first two characters "AL" can be anything but will be only 2 Uppercase characters, followed by a dash(-), followed by a 2 digit number, followed by a dash(-), followed by the rest('Annual DSH Audit.pdf'）.

This is what I have done so far.

```
[A-Z]{2}[\-][0-9]{2}[\-][A]{1}[nnual]{5}\s[DSH]{3}\s[A]{1}[udit]{4}\.[pdf]{3}
```

Please advice. Not sure how to proceed further to simplify this.

Comment: If you want to match a dash after the two upper case characters, then that's exactly what you need to add: `[A-Z]{2}-`. Add the characters you mentioned in your description. If you know how to match two uppercase characters, I assume you know how to match two digits. So what exactly is the problem?

Comment: Will "Annual DSH Audit" always be present, or can that be any string? I get the impression from your question that this is the case, just checking.

Comment: `/^[A-Z]{2}-\d{2}-/`

Comment: @FelixKling fixed the regex. Anyway to simplify this？

Comment: Do all the filenames have to have the substring `"Annual DSH Audit.pdf"` in them?

Comment: `[...]` denote character groups, i.e. "match any one of these characters". Thus `[nnual]` is the same as `[nual]` and `[nnual]{5}` would match `nnnnn` or `nnuul`. If you you literally want to match a specific sequence of characters, then you just write them out as is. Don't use a character group: `Annual\sDSH\sAudit`

Comment: Yeah, looks like the files he uploads should have the same string with same cases

Comment: everything past the last `.` ? Any reason that would not work?

Comment: You should check out this website for testing regex patterns, it's very useful: https://regexr.com/4a34v

Answer (score 2):

`^[A-Z]{2}-\d{2}-Annual\sDSH\sAudit\.pdf$`

*Edited to meet your requirements

Link to demo - https://regexr.com/4a344

Answer (score 0):

```js
const matchesFormat = str => /^[A-Z]{2}-\d{2}-.+\.pdf$/.test(str);

console.log( matchesFormat('AL-13-Annual DSH Audit.pdf') ); // true
console.log( matchesFormat('ZZ-00-test.pdf') );             // true
console.log( matchesFormat('AL-13-Annual DSH Audit.jpg') ); // false
console.log( matchesFormat('AL-13Annual DSH Audit.pdf') );  // false
console.log( matchesFormat('K-13-Annual DSH Audit.pdf') );  // false
console.log( matchesFormat('AL-2-Annual DSH Audit.pdf') );  // false
```

and if you need to also match the ***rest*** `Annual DSH Audit.pdf` than:

https://regex101.com/r/NNtx6o/1

```js
const isAuditPDF = str => /^[A-Z]{2}-\d{2}-Annual\sDSH\sAudit\.pdf$/.test(str);

console.log( isAuditPDF('AL-13-Annual DSH Audit.pdf') ); // true
console.log( isAuditPDF('ZZ-00-test.pdf') );             // false
console.log( isAuditPDF('AL-1-Annual DSH Audit.pdf') );  // false
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
^[A-Z]{2}-\d\d-
```

```js
let t= /^[A-Z]{2}-\d\d-/.test('AL-13-Annual DSH Audit.pdf'); 
console.log(t);
```